# Why nginx shows product list in "html" form instead of "phtml"

Tags: magento2, nginx

When i mouse hover on product list then it shows likes **"dove.html","computer.html"** etc instead of **"dove.phtml","computer.phtml"**.

In apache server it shows **"dove.phtml","computer.phtml"** etc and executes perfectly.

My question is:- how i configure nginx with phtml file then nginx shows product list in "phtml" form.

**here nginx configure file**

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /usr/share/nginx/mydomain.com/;
index index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm;

server_name domain.com;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.(php|phtml)$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is not responsible for links creation process.

I guess you have two Magento instances:

- one has phtml suffix defined in `Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> SEO -> Product URL Suffix`
- second instance is configured to nginx and has default suffix (.html)

So, just change the suffix on the second instance and proceed to nginx setup

Comment: when i set it to .phtml then link not found

Comment: Cache cleanup might solve the issue. If it doesn't, make sure you using links generated by Magento by navigating from the home page. Another possible issue is nginx missconfiguration, for this case please refer to {magento_dir}/nginx.conf.sample file